# Why are my Atom menus displaying in tiny text on Lubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, atom-editor

I would like to use Atom on Lubuntu, but the menu fonts are tiny. What is the best way to fix this? I've found multiple suggestions online (involving editing various config files). Is there actually a right way, or should I just go out and get myself one of those cool jeweler's loupe glasses that I can flip in when I need to read the menus?

Comment: The best place to ask this would be askubuntu.com. It isn't a programming question so isn't on-topic here.

Comment: You may want to ask on the Atom forums at https://discuss.atom.io

Comment: read https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1903400